# Is possible that vector::size() returns a wrong value?

Tags: c++, for-loop

In a c++ programming class, we did an exercise and for the circumstances i decided to use the function "size" of std::vector in a for range instead of iterator. Then my teacher tell me that "sometimes" the function size could return a WRONG value so the for loop could go out of range or not be enough.

I have been writing in c++ for almost 2 years in 4 different compilers and i don't this is true.

**May the size() function of vector return a wrong value?**

EDIT: i agree that this question needs no code because is a theoretical case but i will ilustrate you with the short version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<uint64_t> telephone_nums;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    vector<telephone_nums> telephone_mat;

    // adding elements to telephone_mat

    for (size_t x = 0; x < telephone_mat.size(); ++x){
        for (size_t y = 0, len = telephone_mat[x].size(); y < len; ++y){
            //modification in the matriz...
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not unless you are in undefined behavior. In which case, anything is possible.

Comment: You should show the code in question. The specific usage may be incorrect, but it's not clear from your description.

Comment: Please show us the code that you showed the teacher so that we can answer the question.

Comment: I don't think this question needs code. It seems to be a theoretical question "Can standard function ever be wrong".

Comment: Using size has issue with truncation (if you use a smaller type for the loop index) or if you are iterating backwards but `size` itself can't return a wrong value unless you have undefined behavior from something your code does to the vector.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I'm not sure. It sounds like the context of the question is that OP is looking for validation that they were right in an argument. While the actual question may not need code, the context implies that the answer to the question they asked may mislead them to the wrong conclusion about that context.

Comment: I add for those that wanted to see the code the short version of it. Just to show you how the use of size() isn't incorrect, what my teacher told me is that "size()" "should never be used under no context" (in his words)

Comment: There is **no** occaision where the size returned by `vector::size` will be different from the size implied by the iterators returned by `vector::begin` and `vector::end`. So if that's what your teacher said he's dead wrong.

Comment: @JasonHo If that is what your teacher said then it's ridiculous. What does he think the size function is for if it's never to be used? There are occaisions where the size function is to be preferred to using iterators, for instance when iterators are invalidated because the vector grows or shrinks.

Comment: @JasonHo I would tell your teacher that this is really interesting and could he write some code to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you all, i was pretty sure that was imposible at all and if you don't care i will show his this post in class.

Comment: But calling `size` each loop iteration is wasteful if you are not altering the container--maybe the teacher was talking about that?

Comment: @rsjaffe `for(size_t i = 0, count = vec.size(); i < count; ++i) { ... }`

Comment: @C.M. Right--but that's not what OP was doing.

Comment: @rsjaffe I know :) just wanted to leave that `for` form here. In my experience people practically never use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May the size() function of vector return a wrong value?

Sure. It may return the "wrong" value when the "correct" value that you need isn't the size of the vector.

> what my teacher told me is that "size()" "should never be used under no context"

That's quite silly exaggeration.

In my opinion, it would be more correct to say that there are cases where a loop with indices and `size()` is going to be wrong, despite appearing correct to a beginner. In most cases, while a particular loop would be correct, there is a better alternative that is arguably more readable and less error prone. But there are still some loops where indices and `size()` is superior, although such cases may not be common.

A typical example of a way a beginner unknowingly writes a program that has undefined behaviour, even though the program looks correct in the eyes of a beginner:

```
for (size_t x = 1; x <= telephone_mat.size(); ++x)
```

Another typical beginner mistake:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    if (condition)
        vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
```

An example of a potentially simpler way to write your loops (alghouth whether this applies depends on how the vectors are modified):

```
for (auto& nums : telephone_mat){
    for (auto& element : nums){
        //modification in the matriz...
    }
}
```